# Problem running Mac with VMWare

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I had no problem running it for the first time. Now when I wanted to resume my session I get this:

```
The VMware Authorization Service is not running.
```

Searching on google, I found that that I need to restart the service by entering in msconfig->Services. But I don't have any vmware service there.

Then I tried to open the virtual machine with Run as Administrator, now I get this:

```
The virtual machine could not start. Make sure VMware Workstation is installed correctly and you have rights to run the software and to access all directories it uses, including directories in which the software is installed, directories containing the virtual disk and configuration files, and directories for temporary files.
```

Any idee what else should I do ?

Comment: I'd try reinstalling VMware myself. Are you using VMware Workstation or VMware Player?

Comment: VWware workstation 7.1.4

Comment: is there a reason for you not to try reinstalling? I guess you may be worried you'll lose your VMs? Make a backup copy of them first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed